# Measuring UV light with an photodiode - Is my component selection correct?

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc

I have the following circuit to measure the UV A power with an OpAMP, a [photodiode](https://www.digikey.de/de/products/detail/genicom-co-ltd/GUVV-C20SD/10475476) and an ADC:

[image]

I have simulated the circuit in [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/#) and it looks okay, but I want to hear some additional feedback about the component selection to be sure that the circuit will work as expected.
The circuit should output ~+150 mV when the max UV A power of 6 mW is measured by the photodiode and ~1.65 V when no light is available. The whole circuit is powered by a single 3.3 V supply.

Does this circuit fit into my requirements or does it contain an error?

Comment: I'm guessing that CircuitLab either doesn't take diode capacitance into account, it doesn't take op-amp bandwidth into account, or both.  I expect that in real life it'll oscillate because of the diode capacitance handing off of the op-amp's inverting input.  If so, you'll need some capacitance in parallel with R6 to stabilize it -- and that will slow down your circuit.

Comment: Can you show your design equations, so someone checking doesn't have to look up all the relevant numbers?

Comment: it depends on your specs for tolerance errors from 3.3V and R values. You can eliminate IC6B by inverting the diode with a single supply as it maintains 0V across it with a positive output at 3V/6mW/cm^2

Comment: The 1st error is lack of design specs for sensitivity, and range tolerances.  Do you really want 0 at Vdd/2? Do you know std. R Values are 2.70 and 2.74?  Do you have any other requirements for noise? rail-to rail? . Also it is power density in mW/cm^2 Other than the inverted diode voltage, and C ratio gain effects, the component choice of the diode is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have updated my question

Comment: I've rolled it back. See reasons below my answer.

Comment: @Kampi I'd like to see your own definition of UV A. Given past experience, it seems to have slightly different definitions. But I'm sure you know what you want to look for. So I'd like to hear what that is. Mostly, this is because the shorter wavelength parts of the band are often partially or completely blocked by common forms of clear glass. So you really need to define what you want to measure, I think.

Comment: @jonk my definition is based on the photodiode. Digikey is listing this diode as ` 
UV-A SENSOR (240-395NM)` sensor, so I´m calling it UV-A.

Comment: @Kampi Thanks. That doesn't tell me what you are interested in, though. I assumed you have a purpose in mind. Or, alternatively, it tells me you don't really know what you are interested in except as defined by a manufacturer and you 'believe' that whatever your purpose is, is served by the manufacturer's sensor. The rest of the people here will help with the rest of this, I'm sure. I was only curious if you had a clear vision about your goals, or not. You've answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> *The whole circuit is powered by a single 3.3 V supply.*

That means the op-amps are also powered by the same voltages; 3.3 volts and 0 volts.

> *does it contain an
> error?*

It won't work because the photocurrent of the photodiode will try and raise the virtual ground of the first (left hand) op-amp and, the output of the op-amp would have to produce a negative voltage (lower than 0 volts) to keep the virtual ground at 0 volts. This can't happen without the op-amp having a negative power rail: -

[image]

But, you could turn the photodiode round and that stands a chance of working. And, you probably don't need the 2nd stage op-amp either.

> *Does this circuit fit into my requirements*

Well, your requirements are somewhat defined by what the simulation tells you is produced and, given that this looks unlikely to be correct, I don't think your requirements are very well defined.

And, as Tim Wescott points out in a comment, you will probably need a few pF across your feedback resistor to cut-down on noise and instability.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question.

Comment: @Kampi once an answer is produced, you cannot just incorporate the good information it gives you and reformat your question. I'm going to roll-back your question to where it originally stood. I also suggest that if you are recognizing the info in my answer as useful, you upvote it.

Comment: If you are going to do anything to your question you need to do it carefully so it doesn't make my answer look wrong. If you have a new train of thought given what I have said in my answer then please mention it in a comment and I'll find a way of revamping your question with this new information whilst keeping the original question still current and therefore, my answer still current.

Comment: Thanks. I rotate the diode to remove the negative current and remove the second OpAmp.

Comment: That's a good start and, I seem to remember that your modified question mentioned +/- 2.048 volts but, without a negative and positive power rail, this can't be done.

Comment: The ADC is capable to measure ±2.048 V, but I will only use the positive rail, so the output voltage from the OpAmp should be +2.048 V max.

Comment: The simpler single op-amp circuit will produce close to 0 volts when no light is present and, when light is present, it will produce a positive output voltage. If you know the radiant power of the UV source (watts/sq metre) and, if you know the active area of the photodiode then you can establish the received incident power. Then, somewhere in the data sheet for the photodiode, it will tell you how much output current it produces for the incident power. <-- so, you have the photocurrent and, the output voltage is photocurrent multiplied by Rfeedback.